# log4js configuration error, when trying to run node site.js

Tags: log4js-node

I keep getting this error every time I try running node site.js

> Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:

Anyone have any ideas or know the fix, I am trying to run site.js to start up my site.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're fitted to that syntax in the configure params :

```
log4js.configure({
  appenders: { gouda: { type: 'cheese/appender', flavour: 'tasty' } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['gouda'], level: 'debug' }}
});
```

I've already seen this error. I'was wrong in my code.